# How to order numbers naturally?

Tags: ordering

my entries have simple numbers as title (1, 2, 3, ... 10, 11 etc.). I'd like to order them naturally and not 1, 10, 11, 2, 3 etc. Is Craft allowing this?

Answer (score 5):

I think the simplest solution is to use a plugin like [Twig Better Sort](https://github.com/victor-in/Craft-TwigBetterSort/) or [SuperSort](http://michaelrog.com/craft/lagniappe/supersort). With those you would query for your entries as normal and then apply the Twig filter to sort the array.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('mySection') %}
{% set entries = entries|supersort('natsortAs', '{title}') %}
```